# Moving window in the signal function

Tags: c, linux, gtk, window

I'm writing something like gtk_window_move(w, 0, 0); sleep(5); but the window position changes only after the "sleep" call. I wonder, if you could help me to make this code work correctly. Btw, I use gtk_signal_connect.

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the [`gdk_flush`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-General.html#gdk-flush) function to actually send the command to the server. Note that this is only needed because of the `sleep` call which you shouldn't use anyway (application becomes unresponsive during the time); had you used `g_timeout_add`, gdk would flush the X command queue automatically.

About making widgets visible: this is an operation that requires bidirectional communication between the program and the server, basically, the server asks the client to paint the window and the client responds with commands to draw it. In Gtk, this means you have to let the main loop run. Either:

- setup a timeout for the sleep with [`gtk_timeout_add`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-General.html#gtk-timeout-add), and do the rest of the work in the callback
- run a nested main loop with [`gtk_main`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-General.html#gtk-main) (return from it with `gtk_main_quit`, possibly from a callback of a timeout
- run the loop iterations with `gtk_main_iteration`. This is the least promising approach, because it will be hard to combine it with the sleep.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And what should I do with other actions before "sleep" call like making some widgets visible? gdk_flush does not work in this case.